# Mobile/PDA + SQL Server data synchronization

Tags: mobile, synchronization, replication, sql-server-ce

Need a little advice here.  We do some windows mobile development using the .NET Compact framework and SQL CE on the mobile along with a central SQL 2005 database at the customers offices.  Currently we synchronize the data using merge replication technology.

Lately we've had some annoying problems with synchronization throwing errors and generally being a bit unreliable.  This is compounded by the fact that there seems to be limited information out there on replication issues.  This suggests to me that it isn't a commonly used technology.

So, I was just wondering if replication was the way to go for synchronizing data or are there more reliable methods?  I was thinking web services maybe or something like that.  What do you guys use for this implementing this solution?

Dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used replication a great deal, but I have used it and I haven't had problems with it. The thing is, you need to set things up carefully. No matter which method you use you need to decide on the rules governing all of the various possible situations - changes in both databases, etc.

If you are more specific about the "generally being a bit unreliable" then maybe you'll get more useful advice. As it is all I can say is, I haven't had issues with it.

EDIT: Given your response below I'll just say that you can certainly go with a custom replication that uses SSIS or some other method, but there are definitely shops out there using replication successfully in a production environment.

Answer (score 0):

well we've had the error occur twice which was a real pain fixing :-

*The insert failed. It conflicted with an identity range check constraint in database 'egScheduler', replicated table 'dbo.tblServiceEvent', column 'serviceEventID'. If the identity column is automatically managed by replication, update the range as follows: for the Publisher, execute sp_adjustpublisheridentityrange; for the Subscriber, run the Distribution Agent or the Merge Agent.*

When we tried running the stored procedure it messed with the identities so now when we try to synchronize it throws the following error in the replication monitor.

*The row operation cannot be reapplied due to an integrity violation. Check the Publication filter. [,,,Table,Operation,RowGuid] (Source: MSSQLServer, Error number: 28549)*

We've also had a few issues were snapshots became invalid but these were relatively easy to fix. However all this is making me wonder whether replication is the best method for what we're trying to do here or whether theres an easier method.  This is what prompted my original question.

Comment: Have you tried increasing the insert range for the affected table(s)?

Answer (score 0):

We're working on a similar situation, but ours is involved with programming a tool that works in a disconnected model, and runs on the Windows Desktop... We're using SQL Server Compact Edition for the clients and Microsoft SQL Server 2005 with a web service for the server solution.

TO enable synchronization services, we initially started by building our own synchronization framework, but after many issues with keeping that framework in sync with the rest of the system, we opted to go with Microsoft Synchronization Framework.  (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/default.aspx for reference).  Our initial requirements were to make the application as easy to use as installing other packages like Intuit QuickBooks, and I think that we have closely succeeded.

The Synchronization Framework from Microsoft has its ups and downs, but the only bad thing that I can say at this point is that documentation is horrendous.

We're in discussions now to decide whether or not to continue using it or to go back to maintaining our own synchronization subsystem.  YMMV on it, but for us, it was a quick fix to the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You're definitely pushing the stability envelope for CE, aren't you?

When I've done this, I've found it necessary to add in a fair amount of conflict tolerance, by not thinking of it so much as synchronization as simultaneous asynchronous data collection, with intermittent mutual updates and/or refreshes. In particular, I've always avoided using identity columns for anything. If you can strictly adhere to true Primary Keys based on real (not surrogate) data, it makes things easier. Sometimes a PK comprising SourceUnitNumber and timestamp works well.

If you can, view the remotely collected data as a simple timestamped, sourceided, userided log of cumulative chronologically ordered transactions. Going the other way, the host provides static validation info which never needs to go back - send back the CRUD transactions instead.

Post back how this turns out. I'm interested in seeing any kind of reliable Microsoft technology that helps with this.

Answer (score 0):

TomH & le dorfier - I think that part of our problem is that we're allowing the customer to insert a large number of rows into one of the replicated table with an identity field.  Its a scheduling application which can automatically multiple tasks up to a specified month/year.  One of the times that it failed was around the time they entered 15000 rows into the table.  We'll look into increasing the identity range.

The synchronization framework sounds interesting but sounds like it suffers from a similar problem to replication of having poor documentation. Trying to find help on replication is a bit of a nightmare and I'm not sure I want us to move to something with similar issues. Wish M'soft would stop releasing stuff that seems to have the support of beta s'ware!